# Datatables - Highlighting any of the rows fetched from the server

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am fetching data from mysql and i want to highlight the very first row of the data fetched.

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php"
                } );                
                $('tr:eq(2)').addClass( 'tcurrent' );
            } );
```

The code as is fetches the data,but highlights the table foot.

This is my css

```
.tcurrent{background-color:pink;}
```

Can this be done using one of the existing callbacks?.

Comment: Have you tried `$('tbody tr:first-child')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you your script is running the data from the server may not have loaded into the table.

Since you are using serverside processing, it loads the data asynchronously which means that when `$('tr:eq(2)').addClass( 'tcurrent' )` is executed the table may not contain any rows.

The solution in such cases is to use a load callback method, but in this case I'm not seeing any server load callback in the [datatables documentation](http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks).

One possible solution is to use fnRowCallback

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
  // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
  if ( iDisplayIndex == 2 ) {
    $(nRow).addClass( 'tcurrent' );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried using fnDrawCallback  and its still the same results.

Comment: @Logan try using fnRowCallback, use `iDisplayIndex` to find the row index and add the class to the `nRow`

Comment: This highlights the second column `"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
     $('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass( 'current' );
     }`

Comment: That works,but because of specificity issues i used     `$(nRow).css('background','pink');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in `css`

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(3){
    background-color:pink;
}
```

**Updated**

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "scripts/server_processing.php",
      "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
          $('#example tr:eq(2)').addClass( 'tcurrent' );
      }
});
```

Read Docs http://datatables.net/ref#fnDrawCallback

Comment: @Logan Ztest the above answer I have made changes in it.

Comment: I was having some success with your past suggesion on the row callback but it was highlighting the second column and not row.The code you posted was the same one i was using that was highlighting the foot and the head of the table depending on the `eq()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('tr:eq(2)')` is selecting the third row.

If you want the first, use either `$('tr:eq(0)')` or `$('tr:first')`

Comment: That highlights the header.

Comment: In that case, use `$('tr:eq(1)')` for the next one.

Comment: That highlights  the footer.I am trying using callbacks.